# sklearn.ensemble Can you use less estimators than the number trained in final model?

Tags: scikit-learn

Most `sklearn.ensemble` models (`GradientBoostingClassifier`, `RandomForestClassifier` etc.)  take an `n_estimators` param for number of estimators in the ensemble. If you've trained a model with `X` estimators, can you use less than X estimators in your prediction? This can be useful for model selection.

Example: train 800 trees, you might want to see how a 400 tree model performs.  Given that you have an 800 tree model, you should just be able to predict with the first 400 trees rather than training it again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in boosting models, but a bagging model like random forest may not have this option. Decision trees in boosting models are sequential, so to use the first 400 trees from the 800 trees would make sense. But trees in random forest are without sequence, so you would have to randomly sample 400 trees, which I don't think the module offers.

Answer (score 0):

The boosting models (`GradientBoostingClassifier`, `AdaBoostClassifier`, and `HistGradientBoostingClassifier`) all support this through the `staged_xyz` methods.  You don't directly set the number of estimators; instead, you get all the partial predictions, and can extract whichever one(s) you want.

For others like `RandomForestClassifier` there isn't builtin support, but you can access its `estimators_` and do the aggregation of the predictions yourself.  You can also overwrite the attribute `estimators_` with a subset (in a deep copy of the estimator, say) and then use the `predict` functionality directly; I wouldn't count on that working in future versions, but it does work as of 0.22.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  It's a little surprising, doesn't this seem like common practice?  You'd expect you'd want to train maximum complexity and then simplify your model during model selection. Tree depth requires separate models, but otherwise, seems like important functionality.